# What KML fields are supported in the native Google Maps application on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, kml

I have been doing some research on using maps in iPhone applications and it looks like most of my needs can be met passing KML data into the built-in google maps application, but I cannot seem to set the same values (phone, home page, address) that are available when performing a built-in search in the maps application.  Does anyone know if there is any way to set those values, or what fields are available?

UPDATE: With the advent of the 3.0 OS and the Map API, applications no longer need to pass control to the built-in map application, so this question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

KML is not officially supported by Apple as of now. It's specified in the URL schemes documentation. Any URL in the ?q= parameter will be ignored.

Comment: Except that any URL in the ?q= parameter is not ignored.  I just did a simple test linking to a maps:// address with a specified KML url in Safari on iPhone and it loaded up in the map application correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are few options available for iPhone developers planning to use Google Maps in their software. I've seen sample code and implementations of WebKit that translates gestures to Google Maps loaded inside it, but performance is dismal at best. Doing a static map without a lot of zooming or scrolling is pretty much the only performance-preserving option until a native API is available.

Comment: I realize that using google maps *in* an application is a non-starter at this point, but I was hoping to provide more detail in the maps I can link to in the native app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Developing Virtual Earth iPhone Applications with Objective-C](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtualearth/archive/2008/11/13/developing-virtual-earth-iphone-applications-with-objective-c.aspx)

Comment: This looks like a promising alternative.  I've already looked at a few solutions using the Virtual Earth APIs and tilesets, but as the native maps app was nearly able to satisfy all my requirements, I was hoping to take it that small bit further.